# Reading a comma separated values (csv) file in dynamics ax

Tags: x++, axapta

How do you open and parse a csv file in dynamics ax?

Answer (score 12):

```
static void TestCommaTextIO(Args _args)
{
    #File
    CommaTextIo        commaTextIo;
    FileIOPermission   permission;
    container          containFromRead;
    int                x;
    int                cols;
    ;
    permission = new FileIOPermission('c:\\junk\\mycsv.csv',#io_read);
    permission.assert();

    commaTextIo = new CommaTextIO('c:\\junk\\mycsv.csv','R');

    containFromRead = commaTextIo.read();
    While(containFromRead)
    {
        cols = conLen(containFromRead);
        for(x=1;x<=cols;x++)
        {
            print conpeek(containFromRead,x);
        }
        containFromRead = commaTextIo.read();
    }
    pause;
    commaTextIo = null;
}
```

Comment: one comment: `while( commaTextIo.status == IO_Status::Ok )` of course. The code `While(containFromRead)` is reading `until first empty line`.

Comment: @mazzy would it be safe to do both?

Comment: it's good question. i think `While( commaTextIo.status == IO_Status::Ok )` is safe anyway. I think `While(containFromRead)` is not safe if csv contains empty line as regular data. Fixed