# Getting array from .Net parm method

Tags: .net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to use the .Net class Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser to read in a csv. The problem I am having is that the value of the variable **netArray** appears to be being set to a single string, without the values being split to separate array entries. Any idea as to why this would happen?

```
int counter, xppArrayLength;
str xppValue;
str arr[];
System.String[]     netArray;
System.String[]     delimeters = new System.String[1]();
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(myPath);

delimeters.SetValue(",",0);
parser.set_Delimiters(delimeters);
parser.set_HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes(true);

netArray = parser.ReadLine();

while(netArray.get_Length())
{
    xppArrayLength = netArray.get_Length();
    for(counter = 1; counter <= xppArrayLength; counter++)
    {
        xppValue = netArray.GetValue(counter-1);
        arr[counter] = xppValue;

    }

    netArray = parser.ReadLine();
```

}
}

Comment: Just to make sure, you are aware that there is class CommaTextIO in AX that allows you to read and write csv files? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390940/reading-a-comma-seperated-values-csv-file-in-dynamics-ax)

Comment: No I wasn't. Do you know if that class is able to ignore commas in quotes?

Comment: Yes, it is able to do that (see also https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/66618/121484)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `TextFieldParser.ReadLine()` is supposed to return a single string (as documented here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a8fts4w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You should be doing `parser.ReadFields()` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readfields%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

<s>Also you've not set `TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited` (as documented here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63k8k5sx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)</s> `TextFieldType` default value is `FieldType.Delimited`, so no need to set it.

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally the set_TextFieldType method is asking for an AX FieldType enum, which doesn't seem to be right